# In a UIButton method is there a way to check if SENDER is a subclass of a specific type?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uibutton

Basically if I have a method declared and tied to a button such as:

```
- (IBAction) clickMe:(id)sender {
.....
}
```

Is there a way in this method to see whether **sender** is a subclass of type UIViewController and if so, somehow access something like *[sender.view removeFromSuperView]* ?

Is this at all possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

[isKindOfClass:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBFBDJ)

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates
>   whether the receiver is an instance of
>   given class or an instance of any
>   class that inherits from that class.
>   (required)

to determine if sender is of a certain subclass. After that you should cast sender to UIViewController to remove it's view, else you'll get a warning from the compiler.

Comment: But will isKindOfClass return true if the class is a is a subclass of UIViewController is my question? E.g I have two different UIViewController's that call the same method. I want to simply check if the subclass is of UIViewController and then go..Don't want to specifically check for each subclass name.

Comment: @Straddle if you have class A and B inheriting from class C, both A and B instances will return YES for `[obj isKindOfClass:[C Class]]`

Comment: @Straddle [sender isKindOfClass[UIViewController class]] will return YES if sender is inheriting from UIViewController.